# Can a proxy server view the request and response bodies?

Tags: tls, http, proxy

I'm digging into proxies and VPNs to wrap my head around their security aspects. Wondering: can a proxy server sneak a peek at my raw requests and maybe even tweak them a bit? my connections are HTTPs